# Can a detached rewind crank on a Superheadz UWS leave my film accidentally exposed?

Tags: exposure, film, lo-fi

I'm using a Superheadz UWS toy film camera. After loading the film and closing the backdoor, I went out and took a test shot.

All of a sudden I noticed that the film rewind crank part was detached (the bottom part of the film canister), and immediately fixed it into place.

I'm not sure if my film is exposed, and if i should continue using this roll... would be really sad if I finished it and found out it's all for naught. :-(

I would appreciate it if someone familiar with the workings of this camera could let me know if my film is intact or exposed.

Answer (score 1):

It won't make any difference, except (perhaps) to the film that was already pulled out of the canister. The canister, after all, is designed to keep light off of the film while you handle it in the open, and it does a very good job of it. So your first shot or perhaps the second and the edge of a third might be affected at most. Even then, the light path to the film isn't exactly straight and simple, so anything that is visible would be more along the lines of "interesting lomography-type light leak effects" rather than "OMG, I've ruined the film". The Vivitar UWS clones are all about low-fi, so [learn to stop worrying and love the bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove) — you may wind up with something even more interesting than you had planned.